# jQuery fade to new image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How can I fade one image into another with jquery? As far as I can tell you would use fadeOut, change the source with attr() and then fadeIn again. But this doesn't seem to work in order. I don't want to use a plugin because I expect to add quite a few alterations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**In the simplest case, you'll need to use a callback on the call to [fadeOut()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut)**.

Assuming an image tag already on the page:

```
<img id="image" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" />
```

You pass a function as the callback argument to `fadeOut()` that resets the `src` attribute and then fades back using `fadeIn()`:

```
$("#image").fadeOut(function() { 
  $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeIn(); }); 
  $(this).attr("src", "http://sstatic.net/su/img/logo.png"); 
});
```

For animations in jQuery, callbacks are executed after the animation completes.  This gives you the ability to chain animations sequentially.  Note the call to `load()`.  This makes sure the image is loaded before fading back in (Thanks to Y. Shoham).

**[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hrx5fas0/)**

Comment: The problem is that the new image isn't loaded already hence there is a blink of the new image. (You can see it only if you have empty cache, of course)

Comment: I did say the "simplest case".  Another way would be to preload the 2nd image either with javascript or with another hidden `img` tag.  Fade out the original, then fade in the new.

Comment: Or, you can use `load` event, to determine loading.

Comment: this will actually cause the image to fade into white then fade in again. The user probably want to fade directly from one image to another.

Comment: If the user want it without white-middle, so it's must to be done with background-loading, as Ryan said; although waiting for `load` is good practice anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the .load() trick. This was the solution to my image rotator bugginess ; )

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can place the next image behind the current one, and fadeOut the current one so that it looks like as though it is fading into the next image.

When fading is done, you swap back the images. So roughly:

```
<style type="text/css">

.swappers{
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}

#currentimg{
    z-index:999;
}

</style>

<div>
    <img src="" alt="" id="currentimg" class="swappers">
    <img src="" alt="" id="nextimg" class="swappers">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function swap(newimg){
        $('#nextimg').attr('src',newimg);
        $('#currentimg').fadeOut(
            'normal',
            function(){
                $(this).attr('src', $('#nextimg').attr('src')).fadeIn();
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#main_image").fadeOut("slow",function(){
    $("#main_image").load(function () { //avoiding blinking, wait until loaded
        $("#main_image").fadeIn();
    });
    $("#main_image").attr("src","...");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using the `callback` you pass into `fadeOut` to change the source attr and then calling `fadeIn`? You can't call `fadeOut`, `attr()` and `fadeIn` sequentially. You must wait for `fadeOut` to complete...

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I thought I'd throw in an answer. I use this for the large header image on a homepage. Works well by manipulating the z-index for the current and next images, shows the next image right under the current one, then fades the current one out.

**CSS:**

```
#jumbo-image-wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
}

.jumbo-image
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="jumbo-image-wrapper">
    <div class="jumbo-image" style="background-image: url('img/your-image.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div class="jumbo-image" style="background-image: url('img/your-image-2'); display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
function jumboScroll()
{
    var num_images = $("#jumbo-image-wrapper").children(".jumbo-image").length;

    var next_index = jumbo_index+1;
    if (next_index == num_images)
    {
        next_index = 0;
    }

    $("#jumbo-image-wrapper").children(".jumbo-image").eq(jumbo_index).css("z-index", "10");
    $("#jumbo-image-wrapper").children(".jumbo-image").eq(next_index).css("z-index", "9");
    $("#jumbo-image-wrapper").children(".jumbo-image").eq(next_index).show();
    $("#jumbo-image-wrapper").children(".jumbo-image").eq(jumbo_index).fadeOut("slow");

    jumbo_index = next_index;

    setTimeout(function(){
        jumboScroll();
    }, 7000);
}
```

It will work no matter how many "slides" with class .jumbo-image are in the #jumbo-image-wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want the image to scale according to **width percentage** (which scale according to your browser width), obviously you don't want to set height and width in PIXEL in CSS.

This is not the best way, but I don't want to use any of the JS plugin.

So what can you do is:

1. Create one same size transparent PNG and put an ID to it as
   *second-banner*
2. Name your original image as *first-banner*
3. Put both of them under a DIV

Here is the CSS structure for your reference:

```
.design-banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    #first-banner {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
    }
    #second-banner {
       position: relative;
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Then, you can safely fade out your original banner without the content which placed after your image moving and blinking up and down