# jQuery, change image src with loading image

Tags: jquery, image, loading, src

I have this situation:

```
<div id="main_image">
<img src="images/big_image.png" alt="big image" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
<a href="images/big1.png"><img src="images/thumb1.png" alt="thumb 1" /></a>
<a href="images/big2.png"><img src="images/thumb2.png" alt="thumb 2" /></a>
<a href="images/big3.png"><img src="images/thumb3.png" alt="thumb 3" /></a>
</div>
```

I change the big image src like this code:

```
$("#thumbnails a").hover(function() {
$("#main_image img").attr("src",$(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Before showing the new image, i want to show on the main_image div a loading image, beacuse like this script, if the new image is to big i must wait to render. 
How can i solve this situation?

Tnx

---

FOUND IT:

```
$('#additionals_image_carousel li a').mouseover(function() {
            var href = $(this).attr("href");

            $("#productMainImage img").fadeOut(function() { 
                $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeIn(); }); 
                $(this).attr("src", href); 
            }); 
    });
```

and #productMainImage has a loading image as centered background

[jQuery fade to new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977557/jquery-fade-to-new-image)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading

Comment: How to integrate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading with my example?

Answer (score 1):

1. add loading gif image
2. don't assign the loading actin every time the mouseover actin fired

html:

```
<img id="loading" src="/images/loading.gif" style=" display: none;"/>
```

js:

```
var img = $("#productMainImage img"); 
var loadImg = $("#loading");

$('#additionals_image_carousel li a').mouseover(function() { 
    img.hide(); 
    loadImg.show(); 
    img.attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});

img.load(function() { 
    loadImg.hide(); 
    $(this).fadeIn(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but give it a try , place this div in the main image

```
<div id="load"><img src="images/loading.gif"/></div>

#load
{
display:none;
}
```

Then do something like this

```
$("#thumbnails a").hover(function() {
$("#load").css('display','inline');
});
```

Comment: I want to show loading image before show complete rendered image, not only show a div with loading image. I want to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading but i don't know the best way working for my example.

Comment: @benzo did you try it , what happens when you do that

Comment: Can you check the new solution i've changed on post? It not works on ie7 :(